# Is there a 'standard' way to use Dependency Injection with Java - specifically with JAXRS Jersey

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I have some services that I would like to change from using a factory to using a dependency injection framework.

With Java 6+ is there a 'standard' way that this can be achieved without using third party libraries? Is CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) applicable for this scenario?

Examples would be great! I have started to using Guice that 'seemed' simple, but it's currently causing problems and therefore I'm looking at other options.

Answer (score 1):

DI and CDI are defined bei the Java Standards JSR299 and JSR330. Any DI-Framework that supports these standards will do. For CDI this would be Weld-SE, for DI you could stick with guice, served me well.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of broad. I hope you mean JavaEE 6 when you say "Java 6+"; because Java SE 6 does not provide native DI without 3rd party libs.

Within the Java EE space, the `@ManagedBean` annotation is supposed to serve as standard for all DI needs. Anything annotated with the `@ManagedBean` (from `javax.annotation.ManagedBean` is an eligible target for injection and also eligible to be injected into other beans.

A JAX-RS class for example, is not by itself an eligible target for injection. Adding `@ManagedBean` to it makes it eligible for injection of EJBs, Resources and other context goodies